# How to get LLVM IR AST

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-ir

There's lots of information how to use Clang / LLVM to get the C or C++ AST.  I'd like the **IR** AST.  That is:

Given `xor i1 %1, true`, how do I get something like

```
   xor : i1     # operator, binary
     %1         # operand 1
     true       # operand 2
```

Comment: The IR parser is a hand-rolled recursive descent parser written in C++. It doesn't build up an AST like you speak of, it directly creates the LLVM IR in memory. There's a 1:1:1 relationship between the C++ objects in memory, the bitcode on disk and the textual LLVM IR, so there's no need for any intermediate form like this inside LLVM. Perhaps someone else has written one, but there isn't one as part of LLVM.

Comment: The IR doesn't have an AST, but it has that information. Several LLVM classes have methods called getNumOperands(), getOperand() and operands(). In your case, you can print information about a Value at a given indentation, then if dyn_cast<User> returns nonnull, loop over its operands() and call yourself recursively with increased indentation.